# Which filter is suitable for reducing noise in feature detection?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, feature-extraction, unscented-kalman-filter, particle-filter

I have a feature detection algorithm that is called FAST - Feature Accelerated Segmented Test.

It's a very fast algorithm for finding feature points, e.g "corners" inside an image. Here is one example.

[image]

The problem with these points is that they are moving around very rapidly, like gaussian noise. Still the shape can be viewn.

**Question:**

Is there a way to filter so these points will "move around" less? Like a particle filter, but I don't know if a particle filter can be useful here.

The "dots" comes from a $M \times N$ matrix where $N = 2$ and $M$ can vary a lot. That matrix contains the coordinates for each blue points.

This is how the "dots" looks like.
[image]
https://pastebin.com/wF34Fymr

**Clarifying:**

The blue "dots" are coordinates, and they move around like "vibrating", even if the object inside the picture (hand) is static.

The dots move like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhuE9P5gDJg

Comment: Could you try to explain the problem clearer? For instance, do they move because the hand moves?

Comment: @Royi Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question with more information + a video.

Comment: I am still not sure what do you mean the movement. Do you mean the movement of your hand holding the cards?

Comment: @Royi No, the blue dots are like moving +- steps upwards, backwards, sides due to noise.

Comment: @Royi The blue dots are not floating around uncontrolled.

Comment: OK, If you mean the noise in the image, you need to show the results of matching between 2 non moving objects. You hand moves / shake.

Comment: @Royi The dots "vibrates" is due to noise inside the image.

Comment: @Royi It does not helping if I do some gussian blurring onto the image.

Comment: You need to capture the movement of the dots when you have static video. Then we may build some model of this over time. In the video the movement is generated by both the jitter and your hand movement.

Comment: @Royi Yes, is there any way to remove the jitter? That's the word I'm was looking for.

Comment: @Royi Is it possible to use a particle filter here, or a kalman filter?

Comment: Yes, But to build the model we need to decompose the 2 causes of the change.

Comment: @Royi How can that be done?

Comment: Please, read what I have written several times. To build a solution based on a dynamic filter you need being measurements of a static video where the card is static and not held by hand.

Comment: @Royi What do you mean by "card"?

Comment: In the video you hold a card https://i.imgur.com/RDFUsbO.png.

Comment: @Royi Sorry, I don't understand your text. The video is not static. Sometimes, it can different objects inside the image.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you want to tackle the movement of the feature points from the noise of image you need to give set of points which moves only from the noise. If you talk about the movement around a rigid body, it is a different story.

Comment: @Royi Well, my goal is to have some image classification by knowing interets points, e.g keypoints, the blue "dots". That's my goal. If the dots were stable, then I could easily create a histogram and then classify that histogram.